# Can't login in Fedora 20 (VM) to KDE after password change

Tags: fedora, kde-plasma, password-recovery

I lost my root password so I followed [these](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_reset_a_root_password#Using_GRUB2) instructions. With the bash-4.2# prompt I could successfully change both my root and user passwords and even access my files at /home. Everthing seemed to be fine until I rebooted and tryied to log into KDE as It refuses to recognize my just set password.

Could you save this newbie and tell me am I've done wrong and how to solve this problem?

Comment: Try asking at http://unix.stackexchange.com this is a site for programming questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you did not mention what section you followed on the page you linked.  I'd look at this section:

```
Boot from the install or rescue CD/DVD.
Select "Rescue installed system."
Answer the prompts for language and keyboard. Starting the network is optional and not needed.
Let the rescue mode mount your file systems in the read/write mode.
Hit Enter to get the shell prompt.
At the prompt, enter the following commands. Do not enter any # mark or the text following it. These comments are shown for explanatory purposes only.

chroot /mnt/sysimage   # Change to your disk file system
passwd                 # Change the root password
exit                   # Exit the chroot environment
exit                   # Exit the rescue mode
```

and follow the steps.  I tried it before posting this and it works splendidly.

Hope that helps